# Retrieving facebook city and country

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm trying to retrieve a users city and country by using the FBRequestConnection. gender, id, name seem to work, but cant retrieve the location. It just returns (null), how can i retrieve this?

```
            [FBRequestConnection
             startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                 if (!error) {
                     NSString *facebookId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
                     NSString *facebookName = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
                     NSString *facebookGender = [result objectForKey:@"gender"];
                     NSString *facebookCity = [result objectForKey:@"location"];
                     NSLog(@"%@", facebookCity);
                }

           }];
```

Comment: Have you got the `user_location` permission being granted?

Comment: how can i create this permisson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the response from Graph API

```
{
 "id": "1496537134",
 "name": "XXX XXX XXX",
 "location": {
    "id": "106517799384578",
    "name": "New Delhi, India"
 }
}
```

here location is dictionary , not string.

```
NSString *facebookCity = [result objectForKey:@"location"][@"name"];
```

should work.

before getting location detail, you need to ask for permission, 
[Facebook login with Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0#permissions)

Comment: i think i need some kind of permission, since it still returns (null)?

Comment: @user3837816 yes you need to ask for permission before getting the user location, check this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0#permissions)

Comment: Okay but that code will ask for permisson every time a user logs in. Is there a way to check wether u allready has the permisson?

Comment: no , it will not ask for permission every time. once user will give you permission , at second login attempt it will show that , user has already authorized the permission. check it for your self.